# Do classes affect what can be bought on the citadel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Will a soldier get different items to a infiltrator or vanguard. e.g. different weapons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, all the weapons on the Citadel are the same, regardless of your class.  Even if the weapon isn't "suited" to your class' strengths, you might want to purchase it for a squadmate who uses that type of weapon.

Depending on what you missed or found on missions, you might see more or fewer items, however.  Some of the items you find in shops are actually items that you missed finding while on a mission.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I believe some items are only available for a limited time. I told my friend about the collector armor and when he went to buy it, it wasn't there.
Perhaps you would find that on a mission but I missed it? I'm not sure but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Actually the collector armour is dlc, i know that much.

Comment: @mike1987, I'll check, but I'm pretty sure the Collector Armor is available at the Citadel.  I don't think I've purchased it yet, and I'm pretty far into the game.

Comment: If the Collector Armor is from DLC, it's not any DLC from Mass Effect 3. I have it, but haven't downloaded any additional content.

Comment: @SamuelStandrin - It is not DLC.

Comment: @agent86 I bought my Collector Armor at the Citadel, but my friend went to the same vendor and it was unavailable. I was rather confused by that but your theory of items missed on missions made sense, perhaps that's why? I'm still not sure though.

Comment: Says on wiki it is Dlc

Comment: @SamuelStandrin It's DLC in Mass Effect 2 - not ME3.

Comment: Sorry about my comments then :)